# Jboss Deployment and Java Heap Issues

Tags: java, jboss, jvm, heap-memory

My application was running fine without issues but from last week I am getting one error during jboss start. I have used almost all work around to solve this problem but could not make it.

I am using following options:

```
JBOSS_HOME="/usr/jboss-5.1.0.GA"
JAVA_OPTS="-Xms256m -Xmx850m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m"
```

Log file:

```
2010-09-03 00:53:35,580 ERROR [org.jboss.kernel.plugins.dependency.AbstractKernelController] Error installing to Real: name=vfszip:/usr/jboss-5.1.0.GA/server/default/deploy/elance.ear/ state=PreReal mode=Manual requiredState=Real
org.jboss.deployers.spi.DeploymentException: Error during deploy: vfszip:/usr/jboss-5.1.0.GA/server/default/deploy/elance.ear/jsp/
 at org.jboss.deployers.spi.DeploymentException.rethrowAsDeploymentException(DeploymentException.java:49)
 at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployerWrapper.deploy(DeployerWrapper.java:177)
 at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.doDeploy(DeployersImpl.java:1439)
 at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.doInstallParentFirst(DeployersImpl.java:1157)
 at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.doInstallParentFirst(DeployersImpl.java:1210)
 at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.install(DeployersImpl.java:1098)
 at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractControllerContext.install(AbstractControllerContext.java:348)
 at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.install(AbstractController.java:1631)
 at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.incrementState(AbstractController.java:934)
 at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:1082)
 at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:984)
 at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:822)
 at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:553)
 at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.process(DeployersImpl.java:781)
 at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.main.MainDeployerImpl.process(MainDeployerImpl.java:702)
 at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.repository.MainDeployerAdapter.process(MainDeployerAdapter.java:117)
 at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.repository.ProfileDeployAction.install(ProfileDeployAction.java:70)
 at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.repository.AbstractProfileAction.install(AbstractProfileAction.java:53)
 at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.repository.AbstractProfileService.install(AbstractProfileService.java:361)
 at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractControllerContext.install(AbstractControllerContext.java:348)
 at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.install(AbstractController.java:1631)
 at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.incrementState(AbstractController.java:934)
 at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:1082)
 at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:984)
 at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:822)
 at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:553)
 at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.repository.AbstractProfileService.activateProfile(AbstractProfileService.java:306)
 at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.ProfileServiceBootstrap.start(ProfileServiceBootstrap.java:271)
 at org.jboss.bootstrap.AbstractServerImpl.start(AbstractServerImpl.java:461)
 at org.jboss.Main.boot(Main.java:221)
 at org.jboss.Main$1.run(Main.java:556)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
 at java.util.Arrays.copyOf(Arrays.java:2786)
 at java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream.write(ByteArrayOutputStream.java:94)
 at java.util.zip.ZipOutputStream.write(ZipOutputStream.java:280)
 at org.jboss.virtual.VFSUtils.copyStream(VFSUtils.java:941)
 at org.jboss.virtual.plugins.context.zip.ZipFileWrapper.recomposeZip(ZipFileWrapper.java:368)
 at org.jboss.virtual.plugins.context.zip.ZipWrapper.recomposeZipAsInputStream(ZipWrapper.java:209)
 at org.jboss.virtual.plugins.context.zip.ZipFileWrapper.openStream(ZipFileWrapper.java:211)
 at org.jboss.virtual.plugins.context.zip.ZipEntryContext.openStream(ZipEntryContext.java:1082)
 at org.jboss.virtual.plugins.context.zip.ZipEntryHandler.openStream(ZipEntryHandler.java:153)
 at org.jboss.virtual.plugins.copy.AbstractCopyMechanism.unjar(AbstractCopyMechanism.java:317)
 at org.jboss.virtual.plugins.copy.UnjarCopyMechanism.doCopy(UnjarCopyMechanism.java:52)
 at org.jboss.virtual.plugins.copy.AbstractCopyMechanism.copy(AbstractCopyMechanism.java:176)
 at org.jboss.virtual.plugins.copy.AbstractCopyMechanism.copy(AbstractCopyMechanism.java:135)
 at org.jboss.virtual.VFSUtils.copy(VFSUtils.java:871)
 at org.jboss.virtual.VFSUtils.unjar(VFSUtils.java:852)
 at org.jboss.web.deployers.AbstractWarDeployer.deploy(AbstractWarDeployer.java:360)
 at org.jboss.web.deployers.AbstractWarDeployer.deploy(AbstractWarDeployer.java:97)
 at org.jboss.deployers.spi.deployer.helpers.AbstractSimpleRealDeployer.internalDeploy(AbstractSimpleRealDeployer.java:62)
 at org.jboss.deployers.spi.deployer.helpers.AbstractRealDeployer.deploy(AbstractRealDeployer.java:50)
 at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployerWrapper.deploy(DeployerWrapper.java:171)
 at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.doDeploy(DeployersImpl.java:1439)
 at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.doInstallParentFirst(DeployersImpl.java:1157)
 at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.doInstallParentFirst(DeployersImpl.java:1210)
 at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.install(DeployersImpl.java:1098)
 at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractControllerContext.install(AbstractControllerContext.java:348)
 at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.install(AbstractController.java:1631)
 at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.incrementState(AbstractController.java:934)
 at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:1082)
 at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:984)
 at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:822)
 at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:553)
 at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.process(DeployersImpl.java:781)
2010-09-03 00:53:35,618 ERROR [org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.ProfileServiceBootstrap] Failed to load profile: Summary of incomplete deployments (SEE PREVIOUS ERRORS FOR DETAILS):

DEPLOYMENTS IN ERROR:
  Deployment "vfszip:/usr/jboss-5.1.0.GA/server/default/deploy/elance.ear/" is in error due to the following reason(s): java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
```

Comment: Can you verify that JBoss is picking up your `JAVA_OPTS` via `jconsole` or something?

Comment: elance.ear isnt super huge is it?

Answer (score 1):

Does adding more heap (increase `-Xmx850m`)solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to stop and backup+drop Jboss as's or esb's automatically created tables like above;

JBM_USER JBM_ROLE JBM_POSTOFFICE JBM_MSG JBM_COUNTER ... etc.

Then you should restart server.

This solved our problem.